# Is it possible to return the "highlighted" (like Firebug) css selector or dom id with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firebug

When you click the "Click an element on the page to inspect" arrow with FireBug, it puts a Blue Border around the target element, and also returns the DOM Id.

I am building an application and that feature would be awesome to add.  Be able to hover over elements and highlight the target, upon clicking return the DOM Id or CSS selector to the application.

Is there a jquery plugin that does this magic? Some other smart way?

Thanks!,

Jonathan

Comment: Tster code is short and does exactly that. BTW, this bookmarklet does what you want in simple JavaScript: http://mrclay.org/index.php/2006/02/18/click2zap-bookmarklet/ (in case you need it)

Comment: Did I just get 3 answers in 14 minutes ?!  SO is awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used what tster provided,  and to get the cssPath, i wrote the following `$.fn.cssPath` function which returns me the css selector to reference this element in the future.  So far its working great.

```
          $.fn.cssPath = function() {
            var currentObject = $(this).get(0);        
            cssResult = "";
             while (currentObject.parentNode) {
              if(currentObject.id) {
                cssResult = currentObject.nodeName + '#' + currentObject.id + " " + cssResult;
                break;
              } else if(currentObject.className) {
                cssResult = currentObject.nodeName + '.' + currentObject.className + " " + cssResult;            
              } else {
                cssResult = currentObject.nodeName + " " + cssResult;            
              }
              currentObject = currentObject.parentNode;
            }
            return cssResult.toLowerCase();
          }

   $("*").mouseenter(function() {
      $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
      $(this).addClass("highlight");        
   });

  $("*").bind('click',function(event){
    var value = $(this).cssPath();
    $('#web_page_filter',top.document).val(value);
    return false;
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("*").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".highlighted").addClass("unhighlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
  $(this).addClass("highlighted");
});

$("*").mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("highlighted").parents(".unhighlighted").first().addClass("highlighted");
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Yw4x/14/)

Comment: Instead of binding a handler to every single element on the page, it would be probably better to bind it to the body and use event delegation.

Comment: +1 I used this for the highlighting, see my answer on how I got the css path.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Easily done. What you're interested in is the [`target`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        alert(e.target);
        $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
        $(e.target).addClass("highlight");
        var id = e.target.id; // or $(e.target).attr('id');
    });
});​
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Yw4x/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are some "favlets" (scripts that you add to favorites) that do the similar thing. Here's one: http://slayeroffice.com/?c=/content/tools/modi.html since favlet is just a plain old javascript you can use it's code in your page. Click on "Mouseover DOM Inspector" link to see the effect.